# Methods for bounding the remainder of taylor expansion for $e^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

When I was reviewing taylor series, I ran into trouble on the following problem.

**Problem:**
Write down a Taylor polynomial to compute $e^x$ within $10^{-3}$ of error on the interval $[-1,2]$.

**Solution**
Okay, so we write,
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dotsc+\frac{x^n}{n!}+r_{n+1}$$
where 
$$r_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}e^{\zeta} x^{n+1}$$
for some $|\zeta|<|x|$ and $x\in [-1,2]$. Now we estimate the remainder and see,
$$|r_{n+1}|\leq e^2 \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
and so we want the left hand side of the inequality to be less than $10^{-3}$. After mindlessly computing, the answer is $n=10$. What is a more clever method of determining $n$?

I think Stirling's approximation might be the answer. But that wasn't in the chapter so I feel iffy about using it and I am also unsure of how to manipulate it correctly:

My attempt with Stirlings:
Since 
$$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$ we should have
$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \approx \left(\frac{2e}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}$$
but I don't see how to proceed to make the left hand side less than $10^{-3}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

The review portion also asks the same question but on $[-3,5]$ and I know I'll run into the same trouble. When the interval is $[-1,1]$ it is fairly simple to intuit the correct $n$ by inspection, but I even have trouble applying Stirling's approximation in that case.

So my two questions are: how to use Stirling's approximation in this example, and
can $n$ be found (to satisfy the desired inequality) without Stirling's (or brute force computation)?

Comment: Stirling is an approximation that holds when $n$ is large. You've found that $n=10$ fits the bill, so it's unlikely Stirling will give you the same result.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM great point! That was silly of me to overlook. I had seen it (stirlings) suggested in a similar question but when the interval was $[-1,1]$ but maybe this was misguided as well?